# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping for GET /HelloWorld/helloweb

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting the above warning and my application is not working.Below are my files.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sri</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>HelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <repositories>
 <repository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>5.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
     <finalName>HelloWorld</finalName>
     </build>
      </project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
    </listener>
     </web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.sri.controller" />

  <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>
   </beans>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.sri.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 @Controller
 public class HelloWorldController {
   String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";


   @RequestMapping(value = "/helloweb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      System.out.println("printing");
      return "hello";
   }
    }
```

hello.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
 </head>

  <body>
  <h2>${message}</h2>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Folder structure is as below

[image]

unable to get the requested view.Is there anything wrong in my code or should i add any dependencies.please let me know the detais as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
the url is /helloweb, not /HelloWorld/helloweb
```

Comment: My project name is HelloWorld.On running the project the url is automatically coming as localhost:8080/HelloWorld/ .Should I type localhost:8080/helloweb

Comment: Its nothing related to whats your project name. Defining the context path and then appending the uri is a different thing. In your case, by "localhost:8080/helloweb" you should be able to access the service. Isn't that working?

Comment: the default url can be changed by run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

after spending 18 hour I found answer

In spring mvc, create lib folder under WEB-INF and paste **jstl-1.2.1.jar** file